# Nilpotent vs unstable elements in $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

$\def\sl{\mathfrak{sl}}\DeclareMathOperator\ad{ad}\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\End{End}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$We consider the Lie algebra $\sl_2$ with its usual basis $\{ e,h,f\}$, and denote by $U$ the associated universal enveloping algebra, equipped with its usual filtration 
$$
U_0 \subset U_1 \subset U_2 \subset \dotsb
$$
with $U_k$ corresponding to "differential operators of degree $\le k$". We also fix the ordering $e<h<f$ and the corresponding PBW-basis $\{e^i h^k f^j\}$ of $U$.

In a very nice paper ([Dixmier - Quotients simples de l’algèbre enveloppante de $\mathfrak{sl}_2$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869373901270)), Dixmier describes the group of automorphisms $\Aut(U)$, which naturally contains the reductive group $\PSL_2 = \Aut(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ as a subgroup.  Note that the action of $\PSL_2$ preserves the above filtration.

I am interested in classifying the elements of $U$ in terms of their 
$\PSL_2$-orbits, in the spirit of Geometric Invariant Theory (GIT).

For this, I need two definitions: Given an element $\Phi \in U$

**Definition 1:** We say that $\Phi$ is *nilpotent* if for each irreducible finite dimensional representation $\pi : U \rightarrow \End(V)$, the endomorphism $\pi(\Phi)$ is nilpotent.

**Definition 2:** We say that $\Phi$ is *unstable* if its $\PSL_2$-orbit contains an element lying in the subspace generated by monomials $\{e^i h^k f^j : j > i\}$.

Obviously, this second definition corresponds precisely to the concept of unstability in GIT, and is equivalent to the fact that 
$$
\overline{\PSL_2\cdot \Phi} \ni 0.
$$
Moreover, the implication *Unstable* $\Rightarrow$ *Nilpotent* is obvious, since the condition expressed in Definition 2 implies that $\pi(\Phi)$ is nilpotent for all finite dimensional representation.

Here is what I have observed for the reverse implication:

1) *Nilpotent* $\Rightarrow$ *Unstable* in $U_1$ (this is essentially Morosov's Theorem).

2) The element $\Phi \in U_3$ given by
$$\Phi = \exp( \ad f^2 ) e = e-2fh+2f-4f^3$$
is Nilpotent but not Unstable (this is expected, since the group $\Aut(U)$ is much larger than $\PSL_2$).

For me, the really surprising fact is that the implication
$$ \textit{Nilpotent} \Rightarrow \textit{Unstable} $$
also holds in $U_2$. I proved this with a lot of Gröbner basis computations, by considering a generic element of order 2,
$$\Phi = A + B e + C h + D f + E e^2 + F e h + G e f + H h^2 + I h f + J f^2$$
with coefficients $A, \dotsc,J$ lying in the base field (say $\mathbb{C}$), and showing (by computer) that the polynomial ideals in $\mathbb{C}[A,\dotsc,J]$ corresponding to the nilpotency and unstability conditions coincide.

My question is the following: Is there is a simpler and more conceptual way to treat the $U_2$-case?

Comment: In the language of algebraic groups, one should probably write $\operatorname{PGL}_2$ rather than $\operatorname{PSL}_2$ (since, for example, in your notation $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb R)$ equals $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb R)/\operatorname Z(\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb R))$, not $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)/\operatorname Z(\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R))$.

Comment: What is the paper by Dixmier you mention?  Also, have you seen the paper [Kempf - Instability in invariant theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971168) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=506989)), which seems closely related?

Comment: Here is the reference to the paper of Dixmier:  ** Quotients simples de I’algèbre enveloppante de $sl_2$  - Journal of Algebra, 24, 551-564 (1973)**.  In this paper, he mainly studies the automorphism group of the quotient $B_\lambda$ of $U$ by the ideal generated by $Q-\lambda$, where $Q$ is the Casimir element. But a remark at the end of the paper explains how this allows also to describe a set generators for $Aut U$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the paper of Kempf. I know this work quite well, but I cannot see how it would apply to my problem.   A maximal torus in $PSL_2$ is one-dimensional, and, using Hilbert-Mumford's criteria, this is precisely the condition which implies that the orbit of an *unstable* element of $U_2$ must intersect the subspace generated by $\{e,e^2,eh\}$.